# Why Empty Display Inline Block Element Create Height But Display Inline and Display Block not?

Tags: html, css

Let's think I have container div (block element) and inside have empty inline-block element. In this case container element have height. I think this is because line height. But why if i replace inside element (display inline-block) to block or inline element there are why don't create height?

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div style="display: inline;"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <dis style="display:block;"></dis>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand this you need to know the difference between a **BFC** (block formatting context) and **IFC** (inline formating context.

When having **only** block elements inside your container this one will create a [BFC](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting):

> In a block formatting context, boxes are laid out one after the other, vertically, beginning at the top of a containing block. The vertical distance between two sibling boxes is determined by the 'margin' properties. Vertical margins between adjacent block-level boxes in a block formatting context collapse.

In this case, only the height and margin of the block element inside are considered to calculate the height of your container and you only have one empty element so the height is 0.

When having an `inline-block`/`inline` elements you will trigger the creation of an [IFC](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting) and the story is different:

> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block. Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these boxes. The boxes may be aligned vertically in different ways: their bottoms or tops may be aligned, or the baselines of text within them may be aligned. The rectangular area that contains the boxes that **form a line is called a line box.**
>
> The height of a line box is determined by the rules given in the section **on line height calculations**.

As you discovered, we will be dealing with line boxes and `line-height` will be considered here to define the height of each line box (in your case you have only one)

---

Now, the difference between the `inline` and `inline-block` is about white space. In the case of `inline` element you will end having an empty container because all the white space will collapse. More details here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/text.html#white-space-prop.

If you change the white space algorithm (and you add a space) you will get the same height as with the `inline-block` element.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  margin:5px;
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div style="display: inline-block;"></div></div>

<div class="container"><div style="display: inline;"> </div></div>
```

In addition to white space, `inline-block` are slightly different because:

> Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as replaced inline-level elements, **inline-block elements**, and inline-table elements) are called **atomic inline-level boxes** because they participate in their inline formatting context as **a single opaque box**.

It's not trivial to understand but to use easy words you can see the `inline-block` element as an element where the content inside doesn't interact with the outside world (considering white space, line break, etc) and even if an `inline-block` is empty, we will have a line box

Here is a basic example to see the difference:

```css
.container {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size:30px;
}

div {
  outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  a<div style="display: inline-block;"> some text here </div> text here
</div>

<div class="container">
   a<div style="display: inline;"> some text here </div> text here
</div>

<div class="container">
  a<div style="display: inline-block;"> some text<br> here </div> text here
</div>

<div class="container">
   a<div style="display: inline;"> some text<br> here </div> text here
</div>
```

---

The last case is when you have `inline`/`inline-block` **and** also `block` element in your container. In this case we will trigger a BFC but we have to consider [Anonymous block boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level) where we place the inline elements.

> if a block container box (such as that generated for the DIV above) has a block-level box inside it (such as the P above), **then we force it to have only block-level boxes inside it**.

Then you can see the anonymous block box as an **IFC** and you get a recursive definition. A BFC where you have different blocks and each one can either be a **BFC** or an **IFC** and so on.

---

Related question dealing with the height of inline and block element: [How to determine height of content-box of a block and inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61830546/8620333)

Comment: This is very explanatory answer which and perfect. i just explained using example of `line-height` how it impact. Thanks  upvoted.

Comment: Wooow it was amazing answer it's more detailed. Thank you very much. As far as I understand your answer everything about (in İnline Formating Context) white space. But I don't understand just why inline-block element by default don't have white space collapsing?

Comment: @MuradSofiyev yes it's a bit tricky with inline-block. It does have white space collapsing but still the inline-block is there unline when having inline ... will try to add more clarification on that part to avoid confusion

Comment: @MuradSofiyev added more details

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for update. I started to understand. But İ have question İ don't understand this line "Inline-level boxes that are not inline boxes (such as replaced inline-level elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements)"

Comment: @MuradSofiyev you can consider that some inline level elements are special like image, inline-block element, etc .. these element are called *atomic inline-level boxes*

Comment: @TemaniAfif Okay last question and I think I understand everything in this topic :) You say if block-level box inside have block level box we fore it to have only block-level boxes inside it. Is this mean if i have div (block element) inside p(block element) and span(inline element) inline element will block level?  I'm a little confused here :d

Comment: @MuradSofiyev we will not force the span to be block but the browser will create an anonymous block container to place span inside. To make it easy: imagine that you have many block element and inline element placed inside a div. This will trigger  a BFC because we have block elements. Now the inline elements cannot stay with block element so we create a phantom block element where we place the inline element so that at the end we have only block element at the same level and the inline element are inside the anonymous/phantom block element.

Comment: Woow Thanks currently everything clear in my mind :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif So what actually determines the height of an empty inline-block? The strut? P.s. Do you recommend any book to get the sort of knowledge you reference in your answer (I can't read the 'spec' so if we could avoid that for now).