# Why html and body tag's height differs

Tags: html, css

Just want to understand how the height of the html tag is determined. (In chrome specifically) I am using this sample html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Height of the body is 18px
[image]

I was expecting the height of the html to be 18px + margins(8px + 8px) = 34px. But the actual height is 50px. Whats contributing to the extra height.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this browser depended?

Comment: I am concerned only with chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to consider margin collapsing to find the height.

In your case, you have the default margin applied to `p` equal to `1em` so `16px` in your case. The body is also having a margin equal to `8px` but since `16px` is bigger so it's the one that will win (due to margin collapsing). So the height of html is equal to

```
16px + 16px + height of p element
```

The height of `p` element depend on the content and `font-size`. In your case it's `18px` so you have your total of `50px`

The height of body will only be `18px` because all the margin are outside due to the margin collapsing.

---

More detail:

[How to determine height of content-box of a block and inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61830546/8620333) (to get more detail about the height calculation of `p`)

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 0):

That is not the height of the HTML tag, that margin belongs to the paragraph tag `<p>Hello</p>` and it is common and default in HTML paragraphs as I know.